# What stealthy NES game had that profile-view darkness/searchlight area?

Tags: nes, identify-this-game, game

When I was a kid, probably around 1990-1992, I was at my cousins' house and they played NES. I vividly remember a side-scrolling stage which either was dark the whole time, or alternated between being dark and bright, with spotlights or searchlights that you had to avoid.

Ever since, I've been trying to figure out what game that was.

My suspicions were "Metal Gear" and "Mission Impossible". However, I've previously (and now) looked at playthrough videos of those games and could not spot that stage.

I believe it was not the very first stage, but at the very least the second, or "well into the game". Might even be one of last, if not *the* very last stage.

Can you help me figure out which game this was? I want to revisit that area in particular, and it's really frustrating to not know what the game was called.

I frustratingly cannot remember anything else besides that level. I don't think it was a very obscure game, and it may still be one of the titles I mentioned above, and I just somehow missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Could it possibly be [Rescue - The Embassy Mission](https://youtu.be/fzATD1D6yyQ?t=77) (Youtube link, cued up)? That's the retitled NES port of the Infogrames title [Hostages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostages_(video_game)); it plays as a series of minigames with spotlight avoidance being one of them.

Comment: That pretty much *has* to be it! Although I can't say that I'm 100% sure, because at least from my memory, they seemed to be on some kind of bridge, and the entire screen went dark except for the spotlights for some parts. (But even if that's not the right game, it looks interesting in its own right, with those first-person Deja Vu-like parts and whatnot!)